# Beaglebone Black - Power sensors after boot

Tags: power-supply, transistors, gpio, beaglebone-black

I am new to electronics and want to build a small thermometer/humidity sensor powered by a beaglebone black to get started on something practical.

My issue is that the board doesn't start when the sensors are powered. My connections are equivalent to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0iK5H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 5V is coming from a barrel jack and it receives power even when the BBB is shutdown. And this is bad, according to the manual: "DO NOT APPLY VOLTAGE TO ANY I/O PIN WHEN POWER IS NOT SUPPLIED TO THE BOARD". Which is true, if I power my sensors after the board is booted, everything works fine. Otherwise the board won't boot.

Is there a simple way to add a GPIO controlled switch on the 5V rail between the barrel jack and my sensor array ? Is a PNP transistor enough ? Do I have to use a relay ?

The previous answers I found here talked about a tri-state buffer, but I couldn't understand how it would relate to my problem. It seemed to only apply to logic gates; Can we source current from a tri-state buffer ? ('im really new to this). Or am i supposed to use 1 tri-state buffer for each of my inputs ? (instead of controlling the power line with it).

This is what I had in mind:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ7J4G.png)</sup>

There would be no voltage applied to ANALOG_IN until SYS_RESET is driven high.

Thank you for the help!

Update:
New schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2uL0R.png)</sup>

I guess I don't need a resistor between Q1 & Q2 as R1 will do the job. Is this correct ?

Comment: Update: Actually it's the opposite for PNP. The current will flow when SYS_RESET is low and not high. So i'll have to add a NOT gate in between.

Comment: The updated circuit looks good to me. You could remove Q1 and just put GPIO/SYS_RESET there if you needed to invert the logic. You still need R1 there, and VCC should be the Bone's own voltage output.

Comment: do your resistors need to be as low as 100 ohms? You may not need an external switch, just a GPIO output that is HiZ for off, enabled and high for on. An output might have difficyulty driving 200 ohms directly, but would do 2k easily.